# Можно ли сгенерить ammo.txt из txt файла со списком URL-ов?

Tags: яндекс-танк

Мне поставили задачу обстрелять сайт и предоставили список URL-в, по которым надо стрелять в виде txt файла. Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как-нибудь сгенерить ленту запросов на основании этого файла? 
Предположим, что у меня есть список URL ов в следующем формате :

```
http://www.example.ru/example/179314/
http://www.example.ru/example/81782/
http://www.example.ru/examplet/217302/20092015/
```

и так далее - и их огромное количество.

Каким должен быть ammo файл?

Сейчас для генерации ammo.txt я использую .har файл и утилиту har-to-ammo.

Answer (score 1):

В случае формата https://yandextank.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#uri-style-uris-in-file, передаваемый ammo.txt будет выглядеть так:

```
[Host: www.example.com]
[Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate]
[Connection: close]
...
[прочие http заголовки]
...
/example/179314/ 
/example/81782/
/examplet/217302/20092015/
...
```